# Direct proof that for $X$ an integral scheme with every valuation on $K(X)$ having unique center, the same is true for all closed integral subschemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, valuative-criteria

Suppose $X$ is an integral scheme of finite type over a field $k$, and assume that every valuation on $K(X)/k$ has a unique center. Is there a direct proof that the same is true for every integral closed subscheme $Z\subset X$? This must be the case, because this condition is equivalent to properness of $X\to\operatorname{Spec} k$, and any closed subscheme of a proper scheme is again proper.

Here's what I have in mind, but I don't see how finish the proof:

> Let $Z$ have generic point $\zeta$, and let $R\subset K(Z)$ be a valuation ring. Define $S$ to be the preimage of $R$ under the quotient map $\mathcal{O}_{X,\zeta}\to\mathcal{O}_{Z,\zeta}=K(Z)$. Then $S$ is a local ring, so it is dominated by a valuation ring $T\subset K(X)$. As $T$ is a valuation ring for $K(X)$, there is a unique $x\in X$ so that $T$ dominates $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$.

From here, I need to show that $x$ is a specialization of $\zeta$, and then that $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}/(\mathfrak{m}_\zeta\cap\mathcal{O}_{X,x})=R$. Unfortunately, I do not see how to proceed with these claims. I've looked in the sections of EGA II and the Stacks Project dealing with the valuative criteria, but I haven't found anything that looks helpful. Alternate strategies that are reasonably direct are also welcome.